# Let’s build some Arqade community ads - congratulate our winners!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event, community, community-promotion-ads

> ## Competition closed!
>
> [Winners announced here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14908/28182)

---

Something that I brought up on the [community check in](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13489/28182) post was [reaching out to Stack Exchange sites](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13503/28182) that share similar ball-parks to us, and doing some promotion to increase cross-site involvement. To get the ball rolling on that, why don’t we design some community ads!

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. They are updated yearly, you can check out the ads that are running on Arqade (and have run in previous years) by viewing the questions tagged with the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

### So where are Arqade’s community ads on other sites?

Well, we don’t have any... I’m pretty sure we used to, but they’re more than likely woefully out of date. And with 2020 starting a fresh new decade, it’s high time to see some new designs!

### What are the rules?

Design an ad that promotes Arqade to other Stack Exchange communities, and post it as an answer here. It can either be completely generic, or specifically targeted to one or multiple communities. (I’ve linked some examples below showcasing both).

Here are the image requirements, taken from the 2019 Community Promotion Ads post:

> - The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
> - If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

[Here's an image placeholder at the 600x500 pixel size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4lfa.png)

### Which sites should we target?

Any site that may fit into the broad buckets of computing, gaming, media, entertainment or lifestyle would be the best bet, but if you have a cool idea, any site is on the table!

### How long will the contest run?

To give everyone a fair chance to enter, especially considering the holiday season, the contest will run from **16th Dec, 2019** to **31st Jan, 2020**. We will then have a one-week grace period to allow late entries to accrue votes.

### Prizes?

‘Tis the season, so I’m willing to front up **800 reputation points** in bounties*: **500** for the highest voted design, **200** and **100** for second and third place respectively. Similar to the screenshot competitions - only upvotes will be counted. (In the case of ties I’ll try and split the rewards evenly).

Even if you don’t win - your design may end up being used to promote Arqade, which is still pretty cool.

### Looking for inspiration?

- Worldbuilding has [this cool design](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12302/11061) running on Sci-Fi, and [this other cool design](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8739/51568) on RPG.SE
- Here's an [ad for Movies & TV](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13244/28182) (currently live on Arqade),
- Here's an M&TV one [specifically targeted at the Sci Fi & Fantasy audience](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12298/11061)

  - And in reverse, Here’s an [SFF one on the M&TV site](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4435/4174)

<sub>* Given the limitations surrounding rep transfer, bounties will be raised as ‘Reward Existing Answer’ on your highest-voted answer on the main site, and awarded once the 24 hour bounty lock expires.</sub>

Comment: If you notice any other cool community ads around the network, feel free to link them in the comments (or edit the post if you have the privileges)

Comment: [Something from this type of format?](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/ad-placeholder.png)

Comment: @damadam - something like that yeah. I've added a placeholder image at 600x500

Comment: I've extended the time an extra two weeks to give everyone a fair chance to enter given the holiday season.

Comment: What's the policy regarding the use of footage from games, films, and the like? If these ads are used exclusively on the Stack Exchange network, are copyright  issues a problem, or is this considered fair use?

Comment: @Joachim - Hmm, good questions. I am not a lawyer, - I think it would be best if ads avoid using copyrighted material (screenshots) so we don't have to answer that question when lawyers come knocking. Quotes should be ok though.

Comment: @Joachim Well, we have [this ad](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13244/143571) on our network right now. It's been there for a while, so I assume it's fine...? But I don't have the slightest clue.

Comment: "Must be GIF or PNG;
No animated GIFs"
a slight contradiction, don't you think?

Comment: @Corsaka All that means is if someone prefers working in the GIF format it is allowed, but must make a non-animated GIF (or a 1-frame gif). Not as uncommon as you might think, although PNG has definitely taken over in terms of the de facto web standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Competition closed!

Please join me in thanking everyone that took the time to design and submit a community ad for Arqade, it's very much appreciated. When the community ad posts roll around for 2020, your designs will be used to help promote Arqade and it's wonderful community! Thanks again!

---

Now, on to the winners of the competition! As stated in the announcement post - we will only be counting upvotes, so here we go!

- **1st Place** with **24** upvotes, congratulations to **Dragonrage!** - [A space-themed advertisement](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14842/28182) featuring popular videogaming logos and symbols, with Arqade's little fighter ship taking prominent place. Well done! You've earned 500 reputation points!
- **2nd Place** with **22** upvotes, congratulations to **Batophobia!** - Your [portal-themed advertisement](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14820/28182) has earned you the second place medal! I wouldn't eat it though, the lab boys insist I tell you it's made up of ground up moon rocks. Pure poison! You've earned 200 reputation points.
- **3rd Place** with **18** upvotes, congratulations to **Joachim!** - Your [advertisements with multiple designs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14879/28182) targeting different SE communities are interesting, cool, fun and a little freaky! Well done! You take home 100 reputation points.

---

Thanks once again for everyone that participated! Be sure to keep an eye out for future competitions!

Answer (score 24):

[image: explore new worlds]

---

Here is a more rounded, evenly scaled, png version.

[image]

Comment: I like this, but I think changing out the helmet for something more rounded like [this](https://haloce-workshop.webcindario.com/old_resources/hcew_v10/images/launcher_icon.png) or [this](https://halo.bungie.net/images/Inside/History/inline/marathon/marathon_logo.jpg).

Comment: @Batophobia hmm, i could do that. was just thinking that the helmet would be more recognizable

Comment: @arghtype I should be able to do that. I’ll try and remember to once I get off work today

Comment: I like the second one a lot better

Comment: [The Community Promotion Ads post is up so this can be submitted if you want](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14958/218092).

Comment: @Chaosblessed I have posted it on other SE sites’ community promotion ad posts. However the post on our site is for things that will be shone on our site, so it doesn’t really make sense to have ads for our site on our site.

Comment: @Dragonrage oh duh ‍♀️

Answer (score 21):

[image]

Comment: Had Puzzling.SE in mind when making this.

Comment: It might help to use a heavier font (in black), and a border around the arqade logo.

Comment: While the size for high DPI (i.e. Retina display) is 600x500, consider to also take care for the normal display on 300x250. I'm kind of worried if the white text is not so readable on 300x250.

Comment: @Ave is that better?

Comment: @Batophobia looks good, though could be a little better with larger text and smaller imagery (perhaps also drop "Weighted Companion Cube"?). I'd love to experiment with it if you're willing to share the source file.

Comment: @Ave [be my guest](https://github.com/Batophobia/fileShare/blob/master/Untitled.pdn).  I contemplated just changing the quote to "Arqade reminds you that it will never threaten to stab you", which might look better.

Comment: This is pretty cool. Now I wanna make one with Cave Johnson quotes. *"We're not banging rocks together here, we know how to make a quantum space-hole!"*

Answer (score 18):

[image: Mario]

Comment: Was thinking Movies.SE while making this.  [Source file](https://github.com/Batophobia/fileShare/blob/master/Untitled2.pdn) for those that want to make it better.

Comment: What have you done

Comment: It is a great ad, but I am disturbed by the picture on the right. Is that a valid reason to downvote?

Comment: @Dragonrage It's from the [Super Mario Brothers movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108255/).

Comment: @Batophobia I’m aware, it’s still disturbing though :P

Answer (score 16):

Some late entries:

- A 'standard' ad, in white and black:

  [image]  [image]
  (The explosion graphic can be worked into the black version, as well)
- For Movies.SE:

  [image] [image]
  (Not sure if these are recognizable. I have a version where Bill Murray's face is more pronounced.)
- For StackOverflow:

  [image] [image]
  (I know, humour is not my strong suit.)

Comment: Nice work! The Stack Overflow ones would also fit on Game Dev I think :)

Comment: Why is the first Movies.SE footer different from the others?

Comment: the one with eyes is a bit disturbing

Comment: @Batophobia Older design. I updated it.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Snipe some rep!]

Comment: Hi GnomeSlice, I like this design, but it might help to have Arqade's logo or name (or both!) somewhere on the image, as it's not immediately clear where clicking this ad will lead.

Comment: Bottom-left looks like a good place, but I'm no design expert.